# How we can replace an array with new value, and sort them based on specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have an array of object field inside my collection, what I want to do is replace that array values with new values but in sorted order.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({condition}, { "$set": { "arrayField": arrayValue}}, { multi: true, upsert: true }, function (err, user) {

});
```

each object inside array has a field `index` that its value is between 0, and 1.
Now beside the replace operation, I want to insert the new value in sorted order by `index` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can sort array before update.

```
 arrayValue.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
   return obj2.index- obj1.index; // Descending order.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array before updating and mongo will honour it.

```
arrayValue.sort((a, b) => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this result in next way:

```
// sort + map: easy to read but not so efficient.
// looks like the same logic could be done with reduce and some extra computation
return array.sort(...).map((item, index) => { 
    item.index = index;
    return item;
});
```